# Ending an AngularJS connection

Tags: angularjs, http, post, get, connection

How on earth do I do that with AngularJS?

I'm using this code to generate a client side table with a search bar. ASP.NET MVC is the server here.

```
    app.controller('GenTable', ['$http' ,'$scope', '$window',
        function($http ,$scope, $window) 
        {
            console.log("I'm called");
            $scope.CallSearch = function()
            {
                if($scope.SearchField==null)
                {
                    $http.get("https://localhost:(portnumberhere)/project/all").then(function(response) 
                    {
                        $window.Project = response.data;
                        ProjectLength = Project.length;
                        console.log("I'm in get");
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    PostData="";
                    PostData=$scope.SearchField;
                    $http.post("https://localhost:(portnumberhere)/project/filter",PostData).then(function(response) 
                    {
                        $window.Project = response.data;
                        ProjectLength = Project.length;
                        console.log("I'm in post with"+PostData);
                    });
                    PostData="";
                    console.log("I'm not in post with PostData as "+PostData);
                }
            }
            
            $http.get("https://localhost:(portnumberhere)/project/all").then(function(response) 
                {
                    $window.Project = response.data;
                    $scope.Project = $window.Project;
                    ProjectLength = Project.length;
                    console.log("I'm in get table");
                });
                console.log("I'm at end");
        }]);
```

It prints in my console

```
I'm called
I'm at end
I'm in get table
```

​Which paralyzes any other requests like using the search bar.

Comment: What is your actual question? The console output makes sense based on the code you posted. Can you elaborate on exactly what you are expecting that isn't happening for you?

Comment: The program grabs the required sql data to generate a table, but when it comes to the if/else statement (for the search bar) it fails to react to any inputs.

Comment: Even if I disabled the last http.get, my if/else statements won't work.

Comment: There are a couple things wrong here. For one, your if/else statement is inside the CallSearch() function - is that being called? Your `console.log('Im called')` is actually happening at the $scope initiation, not inside the actual function. Also, if you're sending PostData  through `$http.post`, that data needs to be an object, like `PostData={searchTerm: $scope.SearchField}`

Comment: Can't confirm or deny if PostData should be an object than a string since now I'm getting "Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed" although I configured my WebApi.config to have this    <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>